# Denseness along integer action versus denseness along polynomial action

Tags: metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, group-actions, topological-groups

**Set-up**

Say that we have a group generated by a single element '$g$' i.e. $G = \{n g\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} $ which is acting continuously on a compact metric space $(X, d)$.

So given any point $x \in X$, I can talk about the orbit-closure of $x$ i.e. the set $O(x)$ =  $\overline{\{h.x\}_{h \in G}}$ = $\overline{\{(ng).x\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}}$.

Now this time rather than letting the whole group $\{n.g\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ act on $(X, d)$, I only consider the subset $\{f(n).g\}_{n \in\mathbb{Z}}$ acting on the metric space. Here $f$ is some polynomial that has integer roots.

We can again consider the orbit closure $O_{f}(x) = \overline{\{(f(n)g).x\}}$.

$O(x)$ being closed in compact metric space is again compact and now we can talk about $G = \{n.g\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ acting on just $O(x)$.

**Small Definition**

1. *A point  $y \in O(x)$ is recurrent if $\forall$ open neighborhood V of y, $\exists n \in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $[(ng).V] \cap V \neq\emptyset$.*
2. *A point  $y \in O(x)$ is polynomially recurrent if $\forall$ open neighborhood V of y, $\exists n \in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $[(f(n)g).V] \cap V \neq\emptyset$.*

**Question**

If we knew that the set of recurrent points in $X$ is dense, what could we say about set of polynomially recurrent points?

I tried taking $f(n) = n^{2}$ but then realized that integer squares are so negligible in integers that there might not be any recurrent points. And it is only going to get worse as the degree of the polynomial $f$ increases.

However, I do not seem to know how to answer my question one way or the another. I would really appreciate a help/hint/reference at this point.

Comment: Take this comment with a heaping spoonful of salt, but I think that you would have to address hard questions in arithmetic combinatorics even to say anything about the case $f(n) = kn$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, for $k > 1$. If you squint, this case looks like a topological version of the question answered by Furstenberg's multiple recurrence theorem.

Comment: The usual approach when considering fractional parts of polynomials seems to be what you want or very close (H. Weyl, Über der Gleichverteilung von Zahlen mod Eins. Math. Ann. 77, 313–352 (1916)). You can look for example at Sinai's little book on ergodic theory for getting recurrence for almost all coefficients of a given polynomial (the extended action is not uniquely ergodic!).